# Trying to replace the contents of a <script> tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Our Company uses a closed sourced shopping cart system for its e-comreace web site.  The check out page is generated by a cgi script that I can not modify.  I would like to replace the form validation script it generates with my own.  The script I am trying to replace is the second script in the document.  I have inserted the following script in the footer section:

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT")[1].innerHTML = "New Validation Function Here";
```

however when the validation function is called the old one executes, not my new function.

Where am I going wrong?  Is there a better way?

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to replace the old SCRIPT tag that was already executed.

The validation function is just a value, and the function name is a variable, so you could just do this:

```
<script>

oldValidationFunctionName = function(param1, param2, whatever) {
    // the new function body here...
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably have a better chance at replacing the validation function in the global scope.

```
<!-- Old script file -->
<script>

function doValidate(value) {
 return true;
}
</script>

<!-- New script file -->
<script>
function doValidateNew(value) {
 return false;
}
window.doValidate = doValidateNew;
</script>
```